# Processing Strings into Date Datatype column in RDS using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-rds

A date column in a file(In AWS S3) is in "July 28, 2021" Format.Since it is a file it is being treated as String datatype.I am trying to load the data in to RDS(Postgres).
The RDS Column is in date datatype.

I am using the below line to convert the string into date but NULLS getting loaded in the date column , rest string/integer columns are getting loaded correctly.
`df_S3=df_S3.withColumn('visit_date', to_date(df_S3.visit_date, 'MON DD, YYYY'))`

I changed the date from "July 28, 2021" to "28-JUL-2021" in the S3 File and used the below line of code to process the data into RDS -
`df_S3=df_S3.withColumn('visit_date', to_date(df_S3.visit_date, 'DD-MMM-YYYY'))`

And dates got loaded correctly into RDS.

Could you please advise how to convert/load "July 28, 2021" into a date datatype column using PySpark ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following

```py
df_S3=df_S3.withColumn('visit_date', to_date(df_S3.visit_date, 'MMMM d, yyyy'))
```

Based on the changes communicated in the [latest docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html):

We use `MMMM` to match the full month name, `d` to match the day number and `yyyy` to match the year.

**Full example**

```py
df_S3 = spark.createDataFrame([("July 28, 2021",),("March 5, 2013",)],schema="visit_date string")
df_S3.show()
```

```
+-------------+
|   visit_date|
+-------------+
|July 28, 2021|
|March 5, 2013|
+-------------+
```

```py
df_S3.withColumn('visit_date2', F.to_date(df_S3.visit_date, 'MMMM d, yyyy')).show()
```

```
+-------------+-----------+
|   visit_date|visit_date2|
+-------------+-----------+
|July 28, 2021| 2021-07-28|
|March 5, 2013| 2013-03-05|
+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: @Sonu Great! Please upvote then mark this answer as the accepted answer so that other stackoverflow visitors with similar questions can identify that this answer may solve their problem.